# statvfs system call fails with error Value too large for defined data type

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, system-calls, glibc

I have a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64) installed on my server and have below partitions hierarchy.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       7.9G  1.7G  5.9G  22% /
tmpfs           5.4G  8.0K  5.4G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda8        53G  1.4G   49G   3% /mysql/data
/dev/sda6       7.9G  4.5G  3.1G  60% /usr/BWhttpd
/dev/sda4        32G  989M   29G   4% /var
/dev/sdb1        25T   37M   25T   1% /media1
/dev/sdc1        25T   37M   25T   1% /media2
/dev/sdd1        25T   37M   25T   1% /media3
/dev/sde1        22T   21T  1.1T  95% /media4
```

I issue a `statvfs` call on each of the

> /mediax

partition but the system call fails with error `Value too large for defined data type`.

I was able to find the system call returned error `EOVERFLOW` but not sure which member of `struct statvfs` resulted in this.

Does it have to do anything with the size of the /mediax partitions.

> Note: Partitions are of xfs file system type.

Comment: The output you've posted looks to be from `df`, [which uses `statvfs()` internally](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html), so it seems that `statvfs()` works on your system.  How are you compiling your code?  Are you compiling as 32- or 64-bit?

Comment: @AndrewHenle yes the output is of the `df` command. I am not sure whether 32/64 bit compilation will make difference here. Could elaborate more on this.

Comment: @AndrewHenle also I tried to check the source code of `df` here at http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/df.c but unable to find a reference to `statvfs` I guess it directly uses kernel call `stat`.

Comment: You need to get the entire GNU coreutils package.  The actual file system usage is not determined in `df.c`, it's is found in an internal library function called something like `get_fs_usage()`.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: I verified that you can only get `EOVERFLOW` if you end up using the non-64-bit versions of the stat*fs() syscalls. I added the references to my answer. (For ext4 in particular, you can also take a look at [`fs/ext4/super.c:ext4_statfs()`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/ext4/super.c) to see how ext4 statistics are gathered; it can never fail with EOVERFLOW.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal what was the verification method , also I can't just go and use `64 bit` calls for all system calls since the product has to be supported on `32 bit` and `64 bit` kernel. One more thing is the same `statvfs` call is working fine for 18T partition and failing for 25T partition.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: I traced the kernel call chains (although only completely for ext4). Also, you are absolutely mistaken about the nature of the issue: the native word size, or whether the hardware is 32-bit or 64-bit, has **nothing** to do with the issue here. The issue is that the original structure used for `struct statfs` and `struct statvfs` has fields that cannot describe as large partitions as Linux supports. If even one of the fields would overflow, the syscall returns `EOVERFLOW`. **All linux kernels on all architectures** -- 32 **and** 64 bit -- **since 2.6 support `statfs64()`** etc.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: I rewrote the part in my answer after the horizontal line to make it clearer. To repeat: this is not a 32-bit/64-bit architecture issue; it is just that the original structure used fields that were too small to hold actual real-world values. Since there is existing code using it, the kernel cannot change it; it can only add a new, replacement syscall (for use with new code), that uses a structure with properly-sized fields. This happened over a decade ago, and both are still supported. In your case, glibc just guesses wrong which one it should use, and needs some guidance.

Comment: @NominalAnimal now I understand how `statvfs` and `statvfs64` does internally manages the `struct kstatvfs` between user space and kernel space and why it doesn't throw an `EOVERFLOW` error when we use `statvfs64` call.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: Good to hear! It took me a few tries to get the description of these interfaces in understandable format ... There are a number of other file/filesystem-related syscalls that suffer from a similar issue -- original fields too small, or perhaps not enough fields --, like `lseek64()`; but the `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64` macro should be enough to tell glibc to use the *"better"* versions with just the normal functions (`lseek()`) and types (`off_t`, `struct stat`).

Comment: @NominalAnimal so I can have a mounted file-system of any size and the system call will work in all cases without any failure.  Is there any relation between a file system and the size of the disk formatted with a file system (with single or multiple partitions).

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: Yes, exactly. Various file systems have their internal limits: ext4 cannot exceed 2^60 bytes in theory, xfs 2^63, and so on. Old FAT32 is restricted to 2^41 bytes with 512 byte sectors, and 2^44 with 4096 byte sectors, and so on. The Linux kernel does not care otherwise, but will enforce the limits of the used filesystem, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [`man 2 statfs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fstatfs64.2.html) man page:

> The original Linux statfs() and fstatfs() system calls were not designed with extremely large file sizes in mind.  Subsequently, Linux 2.6 added new statfs64() and fstatfs64() system calls that employ a new structure, statfs64.  The new structure contains the same fields as the original statfs structure, but the sizes of various fields are increased, to accommodate large file sizes.  The glibc statfs() and fstatfs() wrapper functions transparently deal with the kernel differences.

In your case, you are using the non-64-bit versions of the syscalls for some reason.

The Linux kernel implements the `fstat*fs*()` and `stat*fs*()` library calls using four different syscalls (plus optionally their compatibility versions): `fstatfs()`, `fstatfs64()`, `statfs()`, and `statfs64()`. All four are defined in [`fs/statfs.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/statfs.c) in the kernel sources, and use kernel internal function `vfs_statfs()` to gather the necessary information into a `struct kstatfs` structure.

Both `statfs()` and `fstatfs()` use the kernel internal function `do_statfs_native()` (in [`fs/statfs.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/statfs.c)) to copy the fields from a kernel `struct kstatfs` to the userspace `struct statfs` buffer. The problem is, many of the kernel structure fields are larger than the fields in the userspace buffer. The `do_statfs_native()` verifies that the values fit, and if not, will return `-EOVERFLOW` otherwise.

That is the only case I can find that may cause any of the four syscalls to return `-EOVERFLOW`.

For `statfs64()` and `fstatfs64()`, kernel function `do_statfs64()` is used to copy the fields from the kernel-internal `struct kstatfs` to an userspace `struct statfs64` buffer. The userspace buffer fields are at least as large as the kernel structure fields are, so there is no risk of overflow. (The function never returns `-EOVERFLOW`.)

The fix is to ensure you use the 64-bit versions of the `struct statfs`, and the corresponding syscalls.

---

To ensure glibc uses the correct versions (the ones that can correctly describe very large filesystems) of the structures, ensure you have

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

before any `#include`s; or, add `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` to your compiler flags.

All this does is it ensures that glibc knows that you are running on a Linux 2.6 or later kernel (3.x, 4.x, and so on), and that it definitely should try and use the versions of the structures with properly-sized fields.

Alternatively, you can define `_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE`, to expose the `struct statfs64` and `struct statvfs64` types and corresponding `statfs64()` and `statvfs64()` wrappers around the syscalls. This avoids letting glibc do any guesswork, and ensures you use the versions of the syscalls that can correctly describe all Linux filesystem sizes.

Both of these options work on all Linux architectures, 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: does this in any way imply that we can mount partitions of any large size or there is still some higher threshold for the partitions.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: No, it does not imply that; only that if a partition can be mounted, we can obtain its statistics exactly as the kernel sees them. As to partition size limits: The partition table format used on the disk can restrict the size of the partitions (which may come as a surprise to some, and is a reason to move to GPT format partition tables for large storage drives). Also, each filesystem does have a limit of how large it can be; for ext4, I think it is 2^60 bytes (1.15e18 bytes). The generic filesystem code should be okay for up to 2^60 bytes, in theory. Not tested, of course!

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but regarding the kernel code (v4.9, I have currently no code of your kernel, but I doubt that this part has changed a lot), you should search for a value > `0xffffffff` for one of the following parameters:  `f_blocks`, `f_bfree`, `f_bavail`, `f_bsize`, `f_frsize`, `f_files` or `f_files`, i.e., any parameter except `f_fsid`, `f_flag`, and `f_namemax`:

```
if (sizeof buf->f_blocks == 4) {
    if ((st.f_blocks | st.f_bfree | st.f_bavail |
         st.f_bsize | st.f_frsize) &
        0xffffffff00000000ULL)
        return -EOVERFLOW;
    /*
     * f_files and f_ffree may be -1; it's okay to stuff
     * that into 32 bits
     */
    if (st.f_files != -1 &&
        (st.f_files & 0xffffffff00000000ULL))
        return -EOVERFLOW;
    if (st.f_ffree != -1 &&
        (st.f_ffree & 0xffffffff00000000ULL))
        return -EOVERFLOW;
}
```

Comment: Which kernel file you are referring here, I could take a look at the same file with my kernel version.  But again things are working fine for 18T drive and fails for 22T drive.

Comment: @Krishna_Oza: fs/statfs.c.